# Proper sized screws to attach whiteboard on wall

Tags: walls, screws, hanging, anchor

I need to attach a 120 x 200 cm (47.2" x 78.7") whiteboard to a concrete wall with some plaster on it, and the whiteboard arrived with 4 screws which seem kind of small to me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I will be attaching the whiteboard in all four corners with these screws, but compared to the size of the whiteboard I find them to be rather small. The whiteboard is 15 kilograms (33 pounds) heavy.

I would like to use the install kit that came with the whiteboard, since I don't have longer screws of the same diameter to fit the wholes in the corners of the whiteboard (and would like to avoid an unnecessary trip to a hardware store to buy some, given the current pandemic) but I'm worried the whole thing will just come apart and fall if I use the provided kit.

So my question is, are these screws appropriate for mounting the whiteboard? Or should I use longer ones? What length would be appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's marginal, but these anchors are strong in shear (where the force is across the screw instead of pulling outwards on it).

I'd use longer screws if I had any on hand but otherwise these will work alright.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have some difficulty drilling deeply enough into the concrete behind the wallboard without making the wallboard portion of the hole too large.  That will leave very little of the insert there to "bite" into the concrete.

I recommend you get some longer wall anchors and screws that will allow you to get the majority of the anchor into the concrete.